# How can I avoid sending two commands at once?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I'm creating a discord bot and part of its commands is to roll dice with different values (d6, d10, d20, d100). I've set it up like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

function commandIs (str, msg){
    return msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("!" + str)
} //Function that shortens all response commands.

client.on ('message', message => {
  if(commandIs("rolld6", message)){
    var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1); 
    message.channel.sendMessage (result);
  } //rolls a d6

  if(commandIs("rolld10", message)){
    var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((10 - 1) + 1) + 1); 
    message.channel.sendMessage (result);
  } //rolls a d10

  if(commandIs("rolld20", message)){
    var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((20 - 1) + 1) + 1); 
    message.channel.sendMessage (result);
  } //rolls a d20

  if(commandIs("rolld100", message)){
    var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((100 - 1) + 1) + 1); 
    message.channel.sendMessage (result);
  } //rolls a d100

})   
client.login('<Discord bot token>'); //Bot token so it can login to Discord
```

The issue I have is when I send '!rolld100', the bot answers as if I sent '!rolld10' and '!rolld100' at the same time since 10 is in 100.

Any possible fixes? I'm also new to javascript so if you could explain what your solution does it would help me a lot.

Comment: If you move the `rolld100` command before the `rolld10` command it will match the 100 before it matches the 10.

Comment: startsWith seems like it is a bad choice. So what is being sent back? What is in the message?

Comment: @forrestmid and the OP needs to use `else if`

Comment: @epascarello Is absolutely right, because it will match the `rolld10` after the `rolld100` if you don't either return the function or utilize an `else if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @epascarello, what is in the message portion of the function could be anything the user sends after the command portion, if I delete it I'm pretty sure the code won't work. What should I use instead of startWith?

Comment: Is it "rolld100 foo bar xxxx"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I can type '!rolld10 <whatever>' and it will roll and ignore anything after it.

Comment: If it is just a space, than I would split and do an exact match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to be a little complicated with duplicated code. You can simplify this down to a few lines of code by using a regular expression

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on ('message', message => {

  const rollMatch = message.match(/roll(\d+)\s/)
  if (rollMatch) {
    const sides = Number(rollMatch)
    var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * sides + 1); 
    message.channel.sendMessage (result);
  } 

})   
client.login('<Discord bot token>'); //Bot token so it can login to Discord
```

Now if you want to do it your way. You basically would need to do

```
if(commandIs("rolld100", message)){ }
else if(commandIs("rolld10", message)){ }
else if(commandIs("rolld20", message)){ }
else if(commandIs("rolld6", message)){ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative code! I'll see if I can make it work.

Comment: What command would you send to the bot with your generalized code?

Comment: When I try to use your code, it says there's an invalid expression on the 'rollMatch' line with the first forward slash.

Comment: Somehow the closing / is missing.